# delete, edit, and details for a user in admin controller MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my app, I am trying to add create, edit, delete, and details actions. 
the Create action seems working just fine. However, in the delete action I have the following:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteAspUsers(string id)
        {
            //this is the users model 
            AspUsers users = new AspUsers();
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

            IdentityUser theUser = new IdentityUser() { Id = users.ID };

            theUser = userManager.FindById(theUser.Id);
            if (theUser != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await userManager.DeleteAsync(theUser);    

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "user was not found");
            }

            return RedirectToAction ("GetAllUsers/");

        }
```

and the view for getting all users in a table as the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentityUser>

@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@using RidesApp.Controllers;
@using RidesApp.Models;


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetAllUsers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminsLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>GetAllUsers</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailConfirmed)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TwoFactorEnabled)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockoutEndDateUtc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LockoutEnabled)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccessFailedCount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteAspUsers", new {id= item.Id})
    </td>
</tr>
    }

</table>
```

I was trying to use the " AspUsers" model that I have but I got an error, so I tried to use the (@model IEnumerable )  and that worked. However, when I click delete I'm getting a "404" error that it wasn't found. 
I was generally use my own dtatbase (connecting it from an sql server). I added the Identity to an existing application. 
So, basically I have my own tables for the users but now I have the aspnetUsers and other tables which was generated after adding the identity framework. this is my current tables:

[image: [this is my current tables]

I'm Also wondering how would I generate the edit and display the users details in the "details" action.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
return RedirectToAction ("GetAllUsers");
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction ("GetAllUsers/");
```

Comment: actually, the url is (~/admin/GetAllUsers /"user's id"), what's not found is the user id . I believe It shouldn't actually generate this url at all, since it's just deleting the user.

Comment: in that case, it would return a 404(page not found) since we deleted the user successfully right? :)

I suggest try to create a model that would return a response whether the request was successful or not, and add it to the redirecttoaction